# Парсинг HTML Java XML парсерами.

Tags: xml, sax, java

День добрый, уважаемые!

Возникла задача - запарсить HTML файл Java парсерами. Я выбрал STAX. Однако в процессе работы парсер выкидывает ряд исключений, связанных с тем, что HTML не является валидным XML. В частности, он жалуется на незакрытые тэги, на странное написание DOCTYPE, на символы &nbsp и прочее.

Я могу как-то обойти это дважды проходя по HTML и выкидывая то, что вызывает ошибку. Могу, не обращать внимание на исключения выкинутые после того, как я получил то, что нужно. Но хотелось бы сделать как надо.

Так есть способ запарсить HTML с незакрытыми и ошибочными тэгами через стандартные Java парсеры, не привлекая сторонних библиотек?

Comment: Может я и не в тему, но вроде бы в яве уже есть специальный хтмл парсер, который можно использовать сразу для написания своего браузера.

Comment: Да, есть. Только его надо отыскать и еще попытаться разобраться.

Comment: А какой конечный результат должен выйти? Может, можно пойти совершенно другим путем, более легким?

Comment: Ну я думаю, с готовым велосипедом можно быстрее разобраться, чем из 3х колесного делать 2х колесный и пытаться ехать =) И я имел ввиду, что это не сторонний продукт.

Comment: Есть HTMLUnit, см. ниже. Можно самому написать разбор, это не сложно, просто должно же быть нормальное решение. Собственно проблема только в том как отключить валидацию в STAX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML по определению не является well-formed XML-документом. Поэтому стандартные XML парсеры не подоходят. Можно попробовать SAX (может и со StAX выйдет) c отключенной валидацией и хитрой работой со всеми событиями парсера, но не факт, что получится.

Чем вызвано нежелание использования сторонних библиотек? Хорошо бы подошли HtmlUnit или TagSoup.

Comment: Нежелание связано с тем, что:

1) не хочется перегружать проект лишними библиотеками из-за того что надо запарсить маленькую табличку.
2) HTMLUnit по слухам имеет утечки памяти; в любом случае он выполняется довольно долго, даже если отключить css и javascripts. ИМХО это из пушки по воробьям.

Собственно мой вопрос был вызван тем что я не знаю как отключить валидацию в STAX. Параметр который там есть в factory ничего не дает.

Comment: Если известно, что это всего-лишь маленькая табличка, то наверное и структура HTML-документа известна. Поэтоу на регулярках распарсить.

Comment: Да, это действительно проще, спасибо.